# parsing inner parenthesis in a file java

Tags: java, regex, parsing, parentheses

Hi I have a file like this

```
classitem A B{

//some info
    item 1{
         subitem1{
         }
         //other subitems
    }
    item 2{
        //subitems
    }
    //other items
}
//other classitems.
```

I need to parse the file so that i can create a subitem object and assign it to respective item object and assign the item object to corresponding class object. How can I parse the inner parenthesis to build such model in java? Any regex or something will help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to match. Could you provide an example of expected output?

Comment: @Siddhartha every file will have several classitems, i will create a class for every classitems and also for every item and subitem. so in every classitem i will have item fields which will be item objects. and item objects contain subitem objects. For example,
classitemAB.item[0].subitems[0].value=10; something like this. My concern is how can I parse the file so that i can get the names classitemsAB, item1 subitem1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a data structure called a stack. (In Java use a class implementing [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) such as LinkedList)

When you come to a left bracket, push the current item onto the stack. When you read right brackets and need to finish items, pop them off the stack. It's a Last In First Out structure.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Comment: yes i know this. but i want to know how can i define a regex for this? like if 'somename{' apears i want to extract the somename property.

Comment: [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is fine for general purposes. It sounds like you should read the documentation for that, and for regexes above. Research before questions please.

Comment: i am aware of the mechanisms, i am looking for some regex patterns.

Comment: If you can read the input, you can match it with whatever patterns you expect. There are plenty of example patterns out there, I'm not going to spend time giving you the specific one that recognizing a parenthesis, since you didn't specify your actual question.